Stuck in black screen after reboot with new NVIDIA drivers - cannot force shutdown
This may be a hardware issue but someone may have insight.
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 on a Dell precision 5570. I just upgraded from 22.04 and I thought perhaps my NVIDIA drivers would need updating too, so I ran sudo ubuntu-drivers install, after which nvidia-smi returned an error message failed to initialize nvml driver/library version mismatch - I read that rebooting might sort things out, but now it has rebooted to a black screen.
Before the driver update, nvidia-smi did show that the NVIDIA drivers were being used, but the Gnome dark mode wasn't working properly which is why I thought they might need updating.
I would normally try rebooting into the GRUB menu or into safe mode but for some reason my power button does not seem to shut down the laptop. The keyboard lights are lit, I hold then button and they fade out after 4 seconds but if I hit any other key they instantly light up again as if the laptop isn't actually shutting down.
The drive is encrypted, I have tried entering the pw blind but no avail.
I can only think that removing the battery or letting the thing die might let me reboot and get into safe mode.
EDIT // Fixed by disconnecting the battery and booting into safe mode, purging nvidia drivers and reinstalling the recommended ones
